# Display HTML pages in WPF application without WebBrowser

Tags: html, wpf

We have an application that transmits data responses over a radio in the form of an HTML page that is then displayed on a mobile device.  The mobile application is beign rewritten in WPF.

We need to display this HTML page in an area of our UI.  I have used the WebBrowser control and it displays the page fine.  However, the WebBrowser gives you no ability to customize.  I have two main stumbling blocks preventing us from using the WebBrowser control for our implementation.

We need to provide particular functionality on a right-click on the control.  I cannot get the built in context menu of the WebBrowser control to not display.

We need to customize the scroll bars, which you cannot do with the WebBrowser.  We deploy on touch screen devices, so thoroughout our appplicaiton we have fatter scroll bars and additional features for scrolling that the WebBrowser control doesn't allow for.

I'd like to find an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

There is a project/product call [Awesomium](http://awesomium.com/), which is based on Chromium/WebKit. It is a commercial product, which used to be [open-source](http://chriscavanagh.wordpress.com/2010/10/04/a-real-net-4-0-webbrowser/).

For .NET/WPF it uses the [AwesomiumSharp](https://github.com/khrona/AwesomiumSharp) wrapper.

Comment: My vote here. It's a shame that MS didn't provide any decent web viewer for WPF. The WebBrowser is a COM wrapper, thus cannot have any benefit in term of visual effects. Bear in mind that the Awesomuim wrapper seems having some issue when the page displayed contains Silverlight sections. This was over one year ago: not sure whether it was solved in the meantime.

Comment: That looks interesting, although we don't qualify for the free license at $2,900 is a lot of money for a what we need it for.  All we want to do is display HTML pages.  It will not be accessing the Internet.  We supply a string of HTML.